# Navigation Bar Style on Modal View

Tags: ios

When I create a modal view with a Navigation Controller I'm unable to set the navigation bar style to be opaque. I must mention that I'm presenting the modal view from another Navigation Controller. Here's the code I'm talking about:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                       initWithRootViewController:detailedViewController];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

//also tried [navController navigationBar] setOpaque:YES]; with no luck  
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; 
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

There should be something I'm missing and I'm unable to see, so any help will be great!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the navigation controller's `navigationBar` is not nil?  Since the `navigationBar` is part of the navigation controller's view, it isn't necessarily loaded when you create the controller.

Comment: `UIBarStyleBlackOpaque` is deprecated, have you tried with `UIBarStyleBlack`?

Comment: @JonathanArbogast, no, I didn't check for navigationBar being created and I can see your point but if I try changing NavigationBar style inside the new view controller, I mean `detailedViewController` I get the same result. Nevertheless I'll check it. Thanks!!!! @Moxy, your are absolutely right!! I'm gonna change it right now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. That had to do with the fact that I was using actually two navigation controllers and the code I put on my original was using the second nested navigation controller.

At this point, I suppose that I have two options, maintain the nesting navController and configure it correctly or, the one I choose, get rid of the second navController, use the main one and push my customView into the first navController.

Thanks all of you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Set `navigationBar.translucent` to `NO`.  If that is not working for you make sure to call `[navController loadViews]` since they may not load them until you present them.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I already tested setting translucent to NO. The other option seems quite intereseting, I'll check it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to call it before doing calls on the viewcontroller to get the effect you want.

Comment: sorry for the delay replaying but I'm not able to test it until today. I'm checking right now. I'll let you know as soon as a test all your suggestions :)